# our nginx server is stopping on its own

Tags: nginx

We have an express app running on port 3000 using pm2 process manager. We are using nginx to reverse proxy the requests to the node app. But all of sudden nginx stops running on its own. It happened a few days ago, we did a restart and it worked then. But today it failed once again. At that time when we check `nginx status` it gives this output,

```
nginx.service - A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2018-09-22 12:38:52 UTC; 1h 43min ago
   Process: 21571 ExecStop=/sbin/start-stop-daemon --quiet --stop --retry QUIT/5 --pidfile /run/nginx.pid (code=exited, status=0/SUCCES
   Process: 21680 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; master_process on; (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Process: 21676 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/nginx -t -q -g daemon on; master_process on; (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 8027 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Sep 22 12:38:51 ip-172-31-27-16 nginx[21680]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
Sep 22 12:38:51 ip-172-31-27-16 nginx[21680]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to [::]:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
Sep 22 12:38:52 ip-172-31-27-16 nginx[21680]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:443 failed (98: Address already in use)
Sep 22 12:38:52 ip-172-31-27-16 nginx[21680]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
Sep 22 12:38:52 ip-172-31-27-16 nginx[21680]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to [::]:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
Sep 22 12:38:52 ip-172-31-27-16 nginx[21680]: nginx: [emerg] still could not bind()
Sep 22 12:38:52 ip-172-31-27-16 systemd[1]: nginx.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Sep 22 12:38:52 ip-172-31-27-16 systemd[1]: Failed to start A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server.
Sep 22 12:38:52 ip-172-31-27-16 systemd[1]: nginx.service: Unit entered failed state.
Sep 22 12:38:52 ip-172-31-27-16 systemd[1]: nginx.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

And this is the nginx `error.log`

```
2018/09/22 12:38:41 [warn] 21539#21539: conflicting server name "example.com" on 0.0.0.0:80, ignored
2018/09/22 12:38:48 [warn] 21641#21641: conflicting server name "example.com" on 0.0.0.0:80, ignored
2018/09/22 12:38:48 [notice] 21641#21641: signal process started
2018/09/22 12:38:48 [error] 21641#21641: open() "/run/nginx.pid" failed (2: No such file or directory)
2018/09/22 12:38:48 [warn] 21642#21642: conflicting server name "example.com" on 0.0.0.0:80, ignored
2018/09/22 12:38:50 [warn] 21676#21676: conflicting server name "example.com" on 0.0.0.0:80, ignored
2018/09/22 12:38:50 [warn] 21680#21680: conflicting server name "example.com" on 0.0.0.0:80, ignored
2018/09/22 12:38:50 [emerg] 21680#21680: bind() to 0.0.0.0:443 failed (98: Address already in use)
2018/09/22 12:38:50 [emerg] 21680#21680: bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
2018/09/22 12:38:50 [emerg] 21680#21680: bind() to [::]:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
2018/09/22 12:38:50 [emerg] 21680#21680: bind() to 0.0.0.0:443 failed (98: Address already in use)
2018/09/22 12:38:50 [emerg] 21680#21680: bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
2018/09/22 12:38:50 [emerg] 21680#21680: bind() to [::]:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
2018/09/22 12:38:50 [emerg] 21680#21680: bind() to 0.0.0.0:443 failed (98: Address already in use)
2018/09/22 12:38:50 [emerg] 21680#21680: bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
2018/09/22 12:38:50 [emerg] 21680#21680: bind() to [::]:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
2018/09/22 12:38:50 [emerg] 21680#21680: bind() to 0.0.0.0:443 failed (98: Address already in use)
2018/09/22 12:38:50 [emerg] 21680#21680: bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
2018/09/22 12:38:50 [emerg] 21680#21680: bind() to [::]:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
2018/09/22 12:38:50 [emerg] 21680#21680: bind() to 0.0.0.0:443 failed (98: Address already in use)
2018/09/22 12:38:50 [emerg] 21680#21680: bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
2018/09/22 12:38:50 [emerg] 21680#21680: bind() to [::]:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
2018/09/22 12:38:50 [emerg] 21680#21680: still could not bind()
2018/09/22 12:38:52 [alert] 21643#21643: unlink() "/run/nginx.pid" failed (2: No such file or directory)
```

Any idea why it is happening? Is something wrong with our nginx configuration or our node app is somehow causing the trouble?

Comment: check apparmour if ubuntu and selinux if centos, this may be the reason

Comment: we are using ubuntu. are you saying we have apparmour installed which is causing the issue? we have not installed anything like that.

Comment: apparmour may be as a default defender, so you do not need to install it

Comment: Hard to say if something is wrong with your Nginx configuration unless you actually post some of it

Answer (score 0):

Per logs it seems something is already using port 80 and 443. It could be anything. Also in some rare cases it could be nginx itself. Then i would reccomend to restart server.

i would start pin pointing what actually uses those port by:

```
# netstat -tulpn | grep :80
# netstat -tulpn | grep :443
```

Then would check `nginx` error logs to find out more

```
tail -n 500 /var/log/nginx/error.log
```

then if you find some other app using those ports you could check what those are:

```
# whatis <appName>
# whereis <appName>
```

If it is caused by different app then you can either turn it of or rebind it to another port.

Hope it helps :)